# Handling git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

In this thread [git submodule add error: does not have a commit checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799562/git-submodule-add-error-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out/75305137?noredirect=1#comment132992857_75305137)

I had the exact same experience as the OP, so I read the responses to see if there was a solution. Several people answered that the solution was to delete the .git file in the added submodule. In that thread I asked "But doesn't that defeat the purpose of the submodule and just turn that tree into a local repository without any connection back to where the submodule came from?" (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75305137/13000598)

So, I'm asking. Is the proper method to handle the situation described by the OP in the original thread to delete the .git subdirectory and, if so, how does that not *defeat* the purpose of *git submodule add*?

Am I wrong in believing that it does defeat *git submodule add*'s purpose?

Comment: “Rather narrowly defined” - really? You think the requirement for an answer to answer the question is narrow? Tough crowd

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67314682/6309), "`does not have a commit checked out`" means the parent repository still think that a subfolder is still a submodule.

It is best to try and [clean any trace of that subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309), before attempting to add it again as a submodule.